# Why does my recursive quicksort algorithm have such lopsided partitions?

Tags: c++, performance, sorting, recursion, quicksort

I have implemented a quicksort algorithm in C++. However, my algorithm runs much slower than my mergesort algorithm. It does run much faster on reversed arrays but otherwise it is takes about four or five times as long.

My algorithm uses recursion, though I don't think it is the problem. I have tried to switch to random pivot instead of median of three pivot choice. That was even slower.

Includes:

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>
#include<iostream>
```

```
unsigned int recurse(int*a,unsigned int length)
{
    int value=0;
    unsigned int depth=0;
    if(length<=1)
    {
        depth=1;
    }
    else if(length==2)
    {
        if(a[0]>a[1])
        {
            value=a[0];
            a[0]=a[1];
            a[1]=value;
        }
        depth=1;
    }
    else if(length==3)
    {
        if(a[0]>a[1])
        {
            value=a[0];
            a[0]=a[1];
            a[1]=value;
        }
        if(a[0]>a[2])
        {
            value=a[0];
            a[0]=a[2];
            a[2]=value;
        }
        if(a[1]>a[2])
        {
            value=a[1];
            a[1]=a[2];
            a[2]=value;
        }
        depth=1;
    }
    else
    {
        //unsigned int fifth=(length>>3)+(length>>4)+(length>>6);
        unsigned int middle=length>>1;
        unsigned int choices[5]={0,middle>>1,middle,middle+(middle>>1),length-1};
        unsigned int left=0;
        unsigned int right=length-1;
        unsigned int index=0;
        for(unsigned int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            index=i;
            while(a[choices[index]]>a[choices[index+1]])
            {
                value=a[choices[index]];
                a[choices[index]]=a[choices[index+1]];
                a[choices[index+1]]=value;
                if(index>0)
                {
                    index--;
                }
            }
        }
        while(right>left)
        {
            while((a[++left]<=a[middle])&&right>left);
            while((a[--right]>=a[middle])&&right>left);
            if(right>left)
            {
                value=a[left];
                a[left]=a[right];
                a[right]=value;
            }
        }
        value=a[middle];
        if(left<middle&&right<middle)
        {
            a[middle]=a[left];
            a[left]=value;
            middle=left;
        }
        else if(left>middle&&right>middle)
        {
            a[middle]=a[left-1];
            a[left-1]=value;
            middle=left-1;
        }
        long double y;
        x++;
        ratio+=y=fabs((long double)(length>>1)-(long double)middle)/length;
        if(length>=1048576)
        {
            cout<<middle<<" "<<length<<" "<<y<<endl;
        }
        depth=max(recurse(a,middle),recurse(a+middle+1,length-middle-1))+1;
    }
    return depth;
}
```

The depth was just for counting recursion depth. I was trying to see if that was a problem.

```
int main(int argl,char**argv)
{
    unsigned int length=0;
    cin>>length;
    cout<<length<<endl;
    int*numbers=new int[length];
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        numbers[i]=(int)rand()%(length<<1);
    }
    time_t start=time(0);
    mergesort(numbers,length);
    time_t end=time(0);
    cout<<end-start<<endl;
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        numbers[i]=(int)rand()%(length<<1);
    }
    start=time(0);
    unsigned int depth=recurse(numbers,length);
    end=time(0);
    cout<<end-start<<endl;
    cout<<"Depth: "<<depth<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: Code for merge sort, as requested:

```
void mergesort(int*a,unsigned int length)
{
    if(length<=1)
    {
        return;
    }
    else if(length==2)
    {
        if(a[0]>a[1])
        {
            int value=a[0];
            a[0]=a[1];
            a[1]=value;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        unsigned int index1=0,index2=0;
        unsigned int divide1=1,divide2=1;
        unsigned int merge=2;
        unsigned int start=0;
        int*b=new int[length];
        while(merge<=length)
        {
            while(index1<divide1&&index2<divide2)
            {
                if(a[start+index1]>a[start+divide1+index2])
                {
                    b[start+index1+index2]=a[start+divide1+index2++];
                }
                else
                {
                    b[start+index1+index2]=a[start+index1++];
                }
            }
            if(index1<divide1)
            {
                for(unsigned int i=index1;index1<divide1;index1++)
                {
                    b[start+index1+index2]=a[start+index1];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for(unsigned int i=index2;index2<divide2;index2++)
                {
                    b[start+index1+index2]=a[start+divide1+index2];
                }
            }
            if(start+merge>=length)
            {
                if(start==0)
                {
                    merge<<=1;
                }
                else
                {
                    start=0;
                    index1=0;
                    index2=0;
                    divide1=merge;
                    divide2=merge<<1>length?length-divide1:merge;
                    merge=divide1+divide2;
                }
                for(unsigned int i=0;i<length;i++)
                {
                    a[i]=b[i];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                start+=merge;
                index1=0;
                index2=0;
                divide1=start+divide1>length?length-start:divide1;
                divide2=start+merge>length?max((int)(length-(start+divide1)),0):divide2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The results, for 33554432 numbers:
Edit, changed my code, updated results:

```
33554432
33554432
8
22
Depth: 765
0.4437349830864823
```

The last number is the average distance the pivot is from the middle. It is at almost 0.45, almost a one to twenty split.

Comment: Recursion gets to 599 depth on the 33554432 size case, and 332 on the 16777216 size case. I don't think that would cause O(n^2) time complexity though.

Comment: That is one brutally complicated quicksort. I recommend comparing what you have with a [reference implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort).

Comment: @user4581301 I looked one of the partitioning algorithms and it is similar to what I've been using, however, after looking at the ways other people have implemented their quicksort, I think I have a small difference in my code. I will try to fix it. I hope it works.

Comment: `max(recurse(a,middle),recurse(a+middle+1,length-middle-1))` - This isn't `std::max`, so my guess is that there is a `max` macro that evaluates its parameters more than once.

Comment: @RaymondChen This is supposed to be `<cmath>`'s max function. It takes the deeper of the two recursive calls and adds one to it. Also it cannot evaluate its parameters more than once as the evaluation is done and only the values are passed through, the max function will only see the resulting values from the recursive calls.

Comment: I don't see a `max` function in `<cmath>`. [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cmath) and [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/) both deny the existence of such a function.

Comment: @RaymondChen You are right I think I am using the `<algorithm>`'s max or <bits/stdc++.h>. I don't believe that is the problem though.

Comment: @dsoi stop "believing" and start proving, one way or another.  Everything has to be right for code to be fast and correct; one thing wrong makes your code slow or incorrect.There is a pile of dangerous stuff here, from using namespace std, raw new/delete, raw pointer use,  manual swaps, many branched ifs...  I'd be surprised if the code did what its writer intended, not by the opposite.  Start adding comments that logically prove invariants that together prove correctness. Or find a known working pseudo code and align your code to it with comments.

Comment: As commented by user4581301, this implementation is complicated. This appears to be a complicated version of [Hoare partition scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme). The key difference is that normal Hoare partition scheme is using tight loops (the two while statements) to scan the array from the ends, before doing a swap, and continuing until the indexes cross somewhere within the array, while your code is using additional variables and conditional (if) statements, which slow the process down.

Comment: I've changed my code to what you said @rcgldr but it is still about three times as slow as merge sort.

Comment: Sure would be nice if you included the "includes".  Code presented does not compile.

Comment: @Gardener Alright I edited my post to have the includes.

Comment: Still looking for mergesort's include.  Mergesort from stdlib.h has a different signature.  I am probably just dumb not to see how this would compile.

Comment: @Gardener I didn't use any built in merge sort I implemented my own merge sort to test it against quick sort. I'll put the code in for that.

Comment: Look at the output of the "sorted" arrays for your ```recurse``` algorithm for ```length```s 50 and 60. Are they sorted? Anndddd you might want to also check the output of ```mergesort```.

Comment: @eric Looks sorted to me. `1 5 6 6 8 16 18 23 23 23 26 29 29 29 29 31 35 37 37 38 39 40 40 41 41 42 42 44 44 46 47 48 48 50 54 56 57 59 62 64 66 70 76 78 82 84 88 90 90 93` for 50, and `6 9 9 10 11 17 17 18 21 23 24 24 26 26 28 30 33 33 34 35 35 36 38 39 40 42 42 43 44 45 46 48 50 56 57 57 58 62 64 65 66 68 69 69 72 76 79 80 84 86 88 90 93 101 101 106 110 110 112 113`

Comment: Watch out for `<bits/stdc++.h>`. Everything in GCC's bits directory is internal implementation stuff and is not meant to be used directly. `<bits/stdc++.h>`, for example is supposed to aid in precompiled headers and speed up compilation. When misused it dramatically slows compilation. Plus by pulling in the entire standard library you've added tens of thousands of identifiers you're not using, resulting in a minefield that only namespaces can save you from. And if you're `using namespace std;` you've stripped away that defense.

Comment: Yeah I'm not including that, the includes are now in the post.

Comment: Recursion depth of 599 on a data set of size 33554432 is unreasonable. It means that you are on average partitioning the objects 3% and 97%. If you were splitting in half, you would expect a depth of 25. This suggests that there is a flaw in your partitioning code.

Comment: @RaymondChen you are probably right, I think I will check the partitions and where the pivot ends up.

Comment: @RaymondChen I checked and it is pretty lopsided, dividing the array in 1 to 24 ratio. However, I've tried to use middle element only as pivot, as well as random pivot, they were both just as lopsided. What now?

Comment: Check that your partitioning result is correct. For example, start with an array that is already sorted. Median of three should divide into two equal halves. This is just debugging.

Comment: @RaymondChen Yes it does divide an already sorted array into two equal halves, however, I realized that my algorithm doesn't even sort correctly. Now I have a bigger problem to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

No other way to do this, but to answer here. If you are going to call `new` make a corresponding call to `delete`.

`rand()` is not that random, consider using a C++11 random library.

For brevity's sake, I have not included your algorithm, but I have made no alterations to it. I have run this code on both Ubuntu and MacOS.

```
int main() {
    // Here are 50 random numbers I get when I use your method, I have put
    // them in a vector.
    std::vector<int> v = {7, 49, 89, 74, 34, 8, 24, 62, 35, 13, 24, 53,12,
                    2, 51, 71, 55, 49, 88, 52, 15, 49, 45, 5, 88, 21,
                    75, 54, 8, 7, 25, 50, 8, 19, 2, 33, 19, 13, 3, 69,
                    31, 80, 49, 72, 77, 65, 44, 43};

    // I set the size of the vector to be the size of this raw array.
    unsigned int length = v.size();

    int* numbers= new int[length];

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        numbers[i] = v[i];

    // 7 49 89 74 34 8 24 62 35 13 24 53 12 2 51 71 55...
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        std::cout << numbers[i] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    unsigned int depth = recurse(numbers, length);

    // 5 2 3 2 7 7 8 12 8 13 8 13 15 19 19 24...
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        std::cout << numbers[i] << " ";

    delete[] numbers;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm pretty interested in what is going on here. Maybe I am mistaken somehow, but either way I hope this helps (at least one of us).

As for the reason why my answer might matter is that when I run your mergesort algorithm it zero's out everything in the array except for the last element in the array. If this is actually the case, perhaps someone else can confirm, then it is probably doing this more efficiently than your quicksort is sorting.

Best,

Comment: That is very interesting. I'm not sure what is really going on here but I think I'll give that a test. Wait, I'm not sure what you mean by zero's out everything in the array except for the last element. Could you please clarify?

Comment: It takes the array it is given and overwrites the original values such that it becomes something like [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0... 89]. I'm just running what you have given us, so ```mergesort(numbers,length)```, but on the numbers that ```rand()``` produces on my machine that I have given you for reference.